# Right Pad String with spaces Matlab

Tags: matlab, padding

So the following code can left pad a string with spaces keeping a max length of max_len (spaces and string included).

```
max_len = 20; 

spacing_arg = ['% ', max_len,'s'];

padded_string = sprintf(spacing_arg, str);
```

Now how to do it efficiently with right padding?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
max_len = 20; 
spacing_arg = ['%-', num2str(max_len),'s'];
padded_string = sprintf(spacing_arg, str);
```

Comment: Better still, use `sprintf('%-*s', max_len, str)`.

Comment: (Ref to comment above) Actually that method does not work correctly.  You should have checked before..

Answer (score 2):

```
max_len = 20;
padded_str = repmat(' ',1, max_len);
padded_str(1:min(20,length(str))) = str(1:min(20,length(str)));
```

Comment: I guess you want to print your space-padded string to somewhere, which will involve using an additional `fprintf()`. Otherwise, this should probably be faster (although less straightforward). Note also that this solution and mine below behave differently when `max_len<length(str)`.

Comment: @GermanGomez-Herrero: Actually, I tested it -- this solution is *slower* than your `sprintf` solution by a factor of about 2.